# How to insert a datatable into an existing Database and overwrite duplicates?

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb

I currently have a data table which adds new rows based on the Access table rows. In the data table, I change the value of certain columns and update them back to the database. I want to write a line of code that overwrites the data if the primary key already exists. I already looked into a query `INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE     name="A", age=19` but I can't find a way to implement this since i'm using a data adapter.

I have made the following code:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
{
    Normen.Clear();
    Normen.Add(-1);
    for (int j = 9; j < 18; j++)
    {
        Normen.Add(Convert.ToInt32(NormDb.Rows[j].Field<double>(i)));
    }
    newRow[i] = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalMethods.LeftSegmentIndex(Normen, Convert.ToInt32(newRow[i + 18])));
}
schoolDb.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

`Normen` is in this case a list with integers i use to calculate test scores which are then inserted into the empty columns i fetched from the database table.

when this code runs, i have a datatable with rows and columns which are identical to the database columns. When this code is done, the other method is triggered to update the data into the datatable like this:

```cs
using (var dbcommand = new OleDbCommand(ZoekQuery, connection))
{
    using (var SchoolAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ZoekQuery, connection))
    {
        OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(SchoolAdapter);
        cb.GetInsertCommand();
        SchoolAdapter.FillSchema(schoolDb, SchemaType.Source);
        SchoolAdapter.Fill(schoolDb);
        Normeringen.Normeer(exportDb.Rows.Count, schoolDb, exportDb, NormDb, normcode);
        SchoolAdapter.Update(schoolDb);
        MessageBox.Show(Success);
    }
}
```

But when the primary key already exists i want to overwrite the record because in this use case it is possible to grade a test with 2 different values. Is there any way i can implement this?

Comment: When a database has a primary key you can only have one row of database with same key.  So you have to use Update instead of Insert.

Comment: Insert into a temp table and then merge.

Comment: Yes i have a database which has export data without grading, and a school database with graded tests. In this situation it is possible that a student needs a new grade so in the school db it has to overwrite the student name. When i use the .Update command to insert the row, it will throw an exception that it can't be duplicate.

Comment: @self You mean a temp datatable containing the entire schooldb that i need to insert in?

Comment: You have a DataTable.  And you don't have a context of what you add or update. So you will have to check each line to know if you want to update or insert. Connection are not cheap and you will do one round trip every time. If you don't want to handle context and what data is new or need update. (EF for exemple will do that, and will only submit change/ SaveChanges). You can bluck insert your data into a temp table, and write a Merge statement that will handle the "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT", and "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE"

Comment: @self Yes that was what i was looking for, thanks!

Comment: It will not be efficient as you will be sending the whole thing instead of "only the change I made". And I really recommend using SQLBluckCopy, if you use this senario, because multiple insert without it will just take ages.

Comment: Yes you're right, i'm going to read the sqlbulkcopy documentation. Thanks!

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is part of System.Data.SqlClient and only works with SQL/Server, not MS/Access